# How to disable zoom in mapdeck?

Tags: r, gis, mapdeck

I'm using mapdeck to handle county level data with thousands of points or more, as an alternative to leaflet, hoping to get a better performance. With leaflet I used to set maxZoom and minZoom to the same level for tiles layer so that zoom gets practically disabled. I checked `mapdeck` function and there doesn't seem to be a similar setting that I can configure. Does anyone know how can I disable zoom?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've just updated the development version (to 0.3.2002 on 20200522) on github to expose `min_zoom` and `max_zoom` arguments, so now you can do this

```
## install development version
# remotes::install_github("SymbolixAU/mapdeck")

mapdeck(
  min_zoom = 5
  , max_zoom = 15
  , location = c(145, -37.8)
  , zoom = 10
)
```

related github issue - https://github.com/SymbolixAU/mapdeck/issues/295